# Running a .java file and instantiating the class contained in it give me different results

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a Java program that is using threads to transfer data through sockets. The issue I am having is in my server manager when I create a thread pool. If for instance I create a thread-pool of 3, waiting for 3 clients to connect, and then manually run CapitalizeClient.java 3 times, everything works fine and I can manage threads/close sockets perfectly fine, but if I create that same thread-pool and then automate the creating of CapitalizeClient.java by instantiating the class within a loop, I run into a huge issue, being that when I go to close a socket every socket in my entire program closes and everything shuts down.

**Here is the class that's giving me trouble**

```
package parallel_hw_6;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class CapitalizeClient {

    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Capitalize Client");
    private JTextField dataField = new JTextField(40);
    private JTextArea messageArea = new JTextArea(8, 60);
    private String name;
    private JTextArea log = new JTextArea(20,20);

    /**
     * Constructs the client by laying out the GUI and registering a
     * listener with the textfield so that pressing Enter in the
     * listener sends the textfield contents to the server.
     */
    public CapitalizeClient() {

        // Layout GUI
        messageArea.setEditable(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(dataField, "North");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(messageArea), "Center");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(log), "East");

        // Add Listeners
        dataField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            /**
             * Responds to pressing the enter key in the textfield
             * by sending the contents of the text field to the
             * server and displaying the response from the server
             * in the text area.  If the response is "." we exit
             * the whole application, which closes all sockets,
             * streams and windows.
             */
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                out.println(dataField.getText());
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Implements the connection logic by prompting the end user for
     * the server's IP address, connecting, setting up streams, and
     * consuming the welcome messages from the server.  The Capitalizer
     * protocol says that the server sends three lines of text to the
     * client immediately after establishing a connection.
     */
    public void connectToServer() throws IOException {

        // Get the server address from a dialog box.
        String serverAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            frame,
            "Enter IP Address of the Server:",
            "Welcome to the Capitalization Program",
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        // Make connection and initialize streams
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 9898);
        in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        // Consume the initial welcoming messages from the server
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            messageArea.append(in.readLine() + "\n");
            System.out.println("initial message: "+i);
        }
        name = in.readLine();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask serverHeartbeat = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               out.println(name+"_IS_ALIVE");
            }
        };
        TimerTask threadHeartbeat = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               out.println(name+"_ALIVE");
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(serverHeartbeat, 1000, 1000);
        timer.schedule(threadHeartbeat, 5000, 5000);
        String response;
         try {
              while((response = in.readLine()) != null){
                  System.out.println("The input is: " + response);
                  Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("([\\w]*)_ALIVE").matcher(response);
                        if (response == null || response.equals("")) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }else if("CLEAR_CONSOLE".equals(response)){
                            messageArea.setText(null);
                        }else if(m2.matches()){
                            log.append(response+"\n");
                        }else{
                            messageArea.append(response + "\n");
                            dataField.selectAll();
                        }

                    }
                    if (response == null || response.equals("")) {
                          System.exit(0);
                      }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                       response = "Error: " + ex;
                }
    }



    /**
     * Runs the client application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CapitalizeClient client = new CapitalizeClient();
        client.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        client.frame.pack();
        client.frame.setVisible(true);
        client.connectToServer();
    }
}
```

**Here is how I'm trying to instantiate n = thread-pool-size instances of the class to connect**

```
 for(int i = 0; i < numClients; i++){
                    (new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          try {
                                CapitalizeClient.main(null);
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(CapitalizeServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                         }
                       }).start();
                }
```

Note: When I instantiate multiple instances of the class this way they DO show up and connect properly as well as allow me to send messages to all of them or even to specific ones, it's just that when I go to close the socket down, ending the connection to one of the clients, it shuts all the clients down and then the server manager.

**Here is a copy of the server manager code for reference.**

```
package parallel_hw_6;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CapitalizeServer {

    private static ArrayList<Capitalizer> allClients = new ArrayList<Capitalizer>();
    private static ServerSocket listener;
    private static ServerSocket listener2;
    private static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private static int threadPoolNum = 0;
    private static Settings s;
    private static RunIt runIt;

    /**
     * Application method to run the server runs in an infinite loop listening
     * on port 9898. When a connection is requested, it spawns a new thread to
     * do the servicing and immediately returns to listening. The server keeps a
     * unique client number for each client that connects just to show
     * interesting logging messages. It is certainly not necessary to do this.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("The capitalization server is running.");
        int clientNumber = 0;
        int settingsClientNumber = 0;
        listener = new ServerSocket(9898);
        listener2 = new ServerSocket(9899);
//        new Settings(listener2.accept(), settingsClientNumber++).start();
        s = new Settings(listener2.accept(), settingsClientNumber++);
        s.start();
//        threadPool(2);
        runIt = new RunIt();
        try {
            while (true) {

//                new Capitalizer(listener.accept(), clientNumber++).start();
                Capitalizer c = new Capitalizer(listener.accept(), clientNumber++, false, s);
                Thread t = new Thread(c);
                t.start();
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A private thread to handle capitalization requests on a particular
     * socket. The client terminates the dialogue by sending a single line
     * containing only a period.
     */
    private static class Capitalizer implements Runnable {

        private Socket socket;
        private int clientNumber;
        private String name;
        private BufferedReader in;
        private PrintWriter out;
        private boolean fromThreadPool;
        private Settings admin;
//        private PrintWriter adminOut;

        public Capitalizer(Socket socket, int clientNumber, boolean fromWhere, Settings admin) {
            this.admin = admin;
//            this.setName("Thread" + clientNumber);
            this.fromThreadPool = fromWhere;
            if (this.fromThreadPool == true) {
                this.name = "Threadpool_Thread_" + clientNumber;
            } else {
                this.name = "Standard_Thread_" + clientNumber;
            }
            this.socket = socket;
            this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
            log("\nNew connection with client# " + clientNumber + " at " + socket);
            allClients.add(this);
            System.out.print("\n" + allClients);
            try {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
//                adminOut = new PrintWriter(adminSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

        /**
         * Services this thread's client by first sending the client a welcome
         * message then repeatedly reading strings and sending back the
         * capitalized version of the string.
         */
        public void run() {
            try {

                // Decorate the streams so we can send characters
                // and not just bytes.  Ensure output is flushed
                // after every newline.
                // Send a welcome message to the client.
                out.println("Hello, your name is " + name + ".");
                out.println("Enter a line with only a period to quit\n");
                out.println(name);

                // Get messages from the client, line by line; return them
                // capitalized
                while (true) {
                    String input = in.readLine();
//                    System.out.println("\nInput check: "+ input);
                    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([\\w]*)_IS_ALIVE").matcher(input);
                    Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("([\\w]*)_ALIVE").matcher(input);
                    if (input == null || input.equals(".")) {
                        break;
                    } else if (m.matches()) {
                        admin.showHeartbeat(input);
                    } else if (m2.matches()) {
                        heartbeatToAll(input, this.name);
                    } else {
                        out.println(input.toUpperCase());
                    }
//                    out.println(input.toUpperCase());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log("Error handling client# " + clientNumber + ": " + e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log("Couldn't close a socket, what's going on?");
                }
                log("Connection with client# " + clientNumber + " closed");
            }
        }

        private void sendMessage(String message) {
            try {
                out.println(message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log("Error: Message could not be sent");
            }

        }

        private void terminate() {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log("Couldn't close a socket, what's going on?");
            }
        }

        /**
         * Logs a simple message. In this case we just write the message to the
         * server applications standard output.
         */
        private void log(String message) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }

    private static void threadPool(int numClients) {
        try {

            Thread waitForConnection = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < numClients; i++) {
                            System.out.print("Threadpool" + pool);
                            Capitalizer c = new Capitalizer(listener.accept(), threadPoolNum++, true, s);
                            pool.execute(c);
                        }

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(CapitalizeServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            };
            waitForConnection.start();

            System.out.println("\nInside threadPool() - Number of threads in pool is " + numClients);

//                Works but closes all if you close one                 
            for (int i = 0; i < numClients; i++) {
                (new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            CapitalizeClient.main(null);
//                                CapitalizeClient test = new CapitalizeClient();
//                                test.main(null);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(CapitalizeServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CapitalizeServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private static void heartbeatToAll(String message, String name) {
        String m = message;
        String n = name;
        for (int i = 0; i < allClients.size(); i++) {
            String cName = allClients.get(i).name;
            if (!cName.equals(n)) {
                allClients.get(i).sendMessage(message);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Settings extends Thread {

        private Socket socket;
        private int clientNumber;
        private static PrintWriter out;

        public Settings(Socket socket, int clientNumber) {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
            log("\nNew connection with settings client# " + clientNumber + " at " + socket);
        }

        /**
         * Services this thread's client by first sending the client a welcome
         * message then repeatedly reading strings and sending back the
         * capitalized version of the string.
         */
        public void run() {
            try {

                // Decorate the streams so we can send characters
                // and not just bytes.  Ensure output is flushed
                // after every newline.
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                // Send a welcome message to the client.
                out.println("Hello, you are admin client #" + clientNumber + ".");
                out.println("Enter a line with only a period to quit\n");

                // Get messages from the client, line by line; return them
                // capitalized
                while (true) {
                    String input = in.readLine();
                    int intInput = 0;
                    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([\\w]*)_IS_ALIVE").matcher(input);
                    if (input == null || input.equals(".")) {
                        break;
                    } else if (m.matches()) {
                        out.println(input);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        try {
                            intInput = Integer.parseInt(input);
                            System.out.print("\nintInput: " + intInput);
                            switch (intInput) {
                                case (1):
                                    out.println("Which thread should I terminate?");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < allClients.size(); i++) {
                                        String toAdd = i + " : " + allClients.get(i).name;
                                        out.println(toAdd);
                                    }
                                    while (true) {
                                        String choice1 = in.readLine();
                                        try {
                                            int intChoice1 = Integer.parseInt(choice1);
                                            System.out.print("\nintChoice1: " + intChoice1);
                                            allClients.get(intChoice1).terminate();
                                            out.println("CLEAR_CONSOLE");
                                            out.println("Client number " + intChoice1 + " has been terminated");
                                            if (allClients.get(intChoice1).fromThreadPool == true) {
                                                threadPool(1);
                                            }
                                            allClients.remove(intChoice1);
                                            System.out.println("\nall clients: " + allClients);
                                            break;
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            out.println("Enter a valid client number.");
                                            log(e.toString());
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case (2):
                                    out.println("Send to one or all?");
                                    out.println("1. Choose 1");
                                    out.println("2. Send to all");
                                    while (true) {
                                        String allOrOne = in.readLine();
                                        try {
                                            int intAllOrOne = Integer.parseInt(allOrOne);
                                            System.out.print("\nintAllOrOne: " + intAllOrOne);
                                            switch (intAllOrOne) {
                                                case (1):
                                                    out.println("CLEAR_CONSOLE");
                                                    out.println("Which do you want to send to?");
                                                    for (int i = 0; i < allClients.size(); i++) {
                                                        String toAdd = Integer.toString(allClients.get(i).clientNumber);
                                                        String toPrint = i + " : " + allClients.get(i).name;
                                                        out.println(toPrint);
                                                    }
                                                    while (true) {
                                                        String sendToWho = in.readLine();
                                                        try {
                                                            int intSendToWho = Integer.parseInt(sendToWho);
                                                            System.out.print("\nintsendToWho: " + intSendToWho);
                                                            out.println("CLEAR_CONSOLE");
                                                            out.println("Enter message to send.");
                                                            while (true) {
                                                                String message = in.readLine();
                                                                System.out.print("\nmessage: " + message);
                                                                try {
                                                                    allClients.get(intSendToWho).sendMessage(message);
                                                                    break;
                                                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                                                    out.print("Enter a valid client number.");
                                                                    log(e.toString());
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                            out.println("CLEAR_CONSOLE");
                                                            break;
                                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                                            out.println("Enter a valid choice.");
                                                            log(e.toString());
                                                        }

                                                    }
                                                    break;

                                                case (2):
                                                    out.println("CLEAR_CONSOLE");
                                                    out.println("Enter message to send test.");
                                                    while (true) {
                                                        String message = in.readLine();
                                                        System.out.print("\nmessage: " + message);
                                                        try {
                                                            for (int i = 0; i < allClients.size(); i++) {
                                                                allClients.get(i).sendMessage(message);
                                                            }
                                                            out.println("CLEAR_CONSOLE");

                                                            break;
                                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                                            out.print("Enter a valid client number.");
                                                            log(e.toString());
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                            break;
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            log(e.toString());
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case (3):
                                    out.println("How many threads in the pool?");
                                    while (true) {
                                        String numThreads = in.readLine();
                                        try {
                                            int intNumThreads = Integer.parseInt(numThreads);
                                            System.out.print("\nintNumThreads: " + intNumThreads);
                                            out.println("CLEAR_CONSOLE");
                                            out.println("Thread pool with" + intNumThreads + " has been created!");
                                            out.println("Spawn new instance(s) of 'CapitalizeClient' class to utilize it.");
                                            threadPool(intNumThreads);
                                            break;
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            out.println("Enter a valid number.");
                                            log(e.toString());
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    out.println("Please enter a valid option.");
                                    break;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.print("\nnumber format exception\n");
                            out.println("Please enter a valid option.");
                        }

                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log("Error handling client# " + clientNumber + ": " + e);
            } finally {
                System.out.print("FINALLY IS EXECUTING!");
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log("Couldn't close a socket, what's going on?");
                }
                log("Here?Connection with client# " + clientNumber + " closed");
            }
        }

        private static void showHeartbeat(String h) {
            out.println(h);

        }

        /**
         * Logs a simple message. In this case we just write the message to the
         * server applications standard output.
         */
        private void log(String message) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using AWT or Swing in your client. Those are themselves not multi-threading enabled, and you run into issues if main threads are closed. There is swing worker etc. to create multi-threading in your application, or you somehow have to decouple the threads from the GUI handling. If you don't then you run into trouble like you're doing now.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, I'm just not sure how to decouple them. Like I said if I just right click the file in NetBeans and run it, no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Of course, because in that case you start different processes. If you just call `main` from another `main` then you don't get that. You can of course call `exec` instead and create new processes from a Java program, just like NetBeans does.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to solve it by using exec to create new processes for each SWIFT client gui.